# Finding indices where True values connect vertically and horizontally with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, boolean

I want to merge certain values that are numerically close.

In this example I'll look to merge anything that can be connected via a neighboring value with a difference less 2.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a = np.delete(a, (3, 7))
matrix = np.abs(a.reshape(-1,1) - a)
matrix < 2
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True]])
```

Starting at the top left corner:

- First move horizontal to find the last true value.
- Then go downwards to find the last true value.
- Repeat both until the square is found.
- Cannot connect True values diagonally.

This would give you the first square that goes from [0,2] to [2,2].

The desired output of this example would be:

[[0, 2], [3, 5], [6, 7]]

Where the values indicate the beginning and end of the square. Is there a good way of doing this?

I'd prefer not to loop if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've done this using `np.diagonal` as the basis for the logic.

```
bm = matrix < 2
endcoords = np.argwhere(bm[1:].diagonal() == False)
zers = np.zeros(endcoords.shape)
zers[1:] += endcoords[:-1] + 1
end = np.hstack((zers, endcoords))
end
array([[0., 2.],
       [3., 5.]])
```

I know this excludes the last coordinate, which for my example doesn't give the 'correct' answer. This however, does give the right answer for my workflow as I'm chunking arrays together - so the last missing coordinate will be the first of my next array. It shouldn't be too hard to finagle the right answer from this anyways.